# images not appearing online but appears offline. I am uploading via Filezilla

Tags: image, server, http-status-code-404, filezilla

I am uploading my website using Filezilla, and some images are not appearing. I have checked that the file names are all lower case and that the file type is set to auto instead of ASCII. I have cleared the cache too and I am still not seeing the same images not appearing.

I have got a 403 and 404 error on these images in the console, please see screenshot image for this.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLDXe.png)

All images work fine when testing locally on my computer but some random images are not appearing. Anyone any ideas why this could be?

Thanks!

[image not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lras.png)

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe provide some code with examples?
It could e.g be that the path on the server is different. If you use absolute paths it may work on your host where the homepage is under /. But if it is under /user/ or something similar (so not in the root), the paths can be broken and images will not appear. So check if you provide the paths differently for the pictures that work as opposed to the ones which fail.

Comment: I can provide my website, http://katrinadoyle.com/final-year/Designs-development/design-development.html .   (its a working progress at the moment) would this be useful?

Comment: Check the access right. You should set them to 644 as example for pictures which don't work. Heres a how to for filezilla https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/

Comment: i changed it to 644 and this is appearing on my website now "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /final-year/blog-final-year.html on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: it originally was set to "750"

Comment: Okay then check that the images also have 750 permissions.

Comment: I changed the images to 750 too but when I go back to check it, they are set to 755 again, apologies I am new to using Filezilla. I have never seen this issue before

Comment: Two more things. Try to reupload the images which are not working. Make sure that they have the same permissions as the ones which are already working. And then also check, the .htaccess file and make sure that they are not treated differently in there. But despite of that I don't have any more ideas...

Comment: I reuploaded everything and so far all the images are coming up. Thanks for your help! appreciate it!